Why does matplotlibs bar seem to automatically order by the x-axis?
I have two arrays, one with identifier ids, and one with values, e.g
ids = [1,7,5]
values = [3.0, 9000.0, 2.7]

so 1 belongs to 3.0, 5 to 2.7,....
For whatever reason, no matter what I do, my matplotlib barchart never ends up sorted by y-values.
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ids": ids,
        "values" : values
    }
)

df = df.sort_values("values", ascending=False)
plt.bar(df.index, df["values"], color='skyblue', edgecolor='black')
plt.xticks(df.index, df["values"])

This leaves me clueless, the rest of the function is just cosmetics, e.g setting a title, y_lim,....Why or how does the barchart work here this way? I need this bar sorted by y-values, e.g id 1 with 3.0 as value should be the last bar, and 5 with 9000.0 should be the first one. What am I doing wrong?

df = df.sort_values("values", ascending=False, ignore_index=True)

@Anonymous thanks a lot! Didnt find this piece of information anywhere <3

Try using the pandas built-in .plot() method instead.
Something like df.set_index('ids').plot(kind='bar') gives you sorted values and .plot().


Reset index after setting the order
df= df.reset_index(inplace=False)

Full:
ids = [1,7,5]
values = [3.0, 9000.0, 2.7]


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ids": ids,
        "values" : values
    }
)

df = df.sort_values(by="values", ascending=False)
df= df.reset_index(inplace=False)
df.head()

plt.bar(df.index, df["values"], color='skyblue', edgecolor='black')
plt.xticks(df.index, df["values"])


